# How to automate pmd eclipse plugin execution?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I've just installed PMD plugin in eclipse neon and I already know how to execute it, but I have thousands of projects to be analyzed by PMD and I would like to know if there is a way to automate its execution (like using its source code and calling the specific parts of the code inside my algorithm).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eclipse plugin uses PMD to analyse the files. If you want to automate the analysis then you want to use PMD directly, not the eclipse plugin.

Take a look at the class PMD. It has the static method [PMD.doPMD(configuration)](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/pmd_releases/5.5.0/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/PMD.java#L230) which starts the analysis. The same class also contains the [main method](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/pmd_releases/5.5.0/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/PMD.java#L473) in case you want to start it like from the command line.

You can find an example of how to invoke PMD.doPMD(configuration) in the method [Analyser.runPMD()](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/blob/master/ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.core/src/ch/acanda/eclipse/pmd/builder/Analyzer.java#L69) of the eclipse plugin.